# Crew scheduling with Timefold

Tags: java, mathematical-optimization, optaplanner, timefold

I'm currently trying to model an on-the-fly crew scheduling problem with Timefold. A given set of visits need to be scheduled and assigned to technicians to be carried out. Any number of technicians can be assigned to a visit, and each tech/visit have associated skills possessed/needed.

Is there a simple way, with Timefold, to model this kind of problem; or do I need to go around this problem and maybe imagine a smart way to split each visit by skill and by assigning several of those to the same tech? That's the kind of things done in the flight assignment example, but in this case we know exactly how many employees must be assigned to a flight, and flights have already been scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

These are 2 relevant quickstarts:

- [vehicle-routing-time-windows](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts/tree/stable/use-cases/vehicle-routing-time-windows) - [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJAYChprzgs)
- [maintenance-scheduling](https://github.com/TimefoldAI/timefold-quickstarts/tree/stable/use-cases/maintenance-scheduling) - [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RFm_tJhSlYg)

I suspect the vehicle routing one is the better fit, because it uses a **chained through time pattern** (see docs "design patterns").

That being said, the *on-the-fly* requirement sounds like **Real-Time Planning**. We'll release a short video on that later this week. Basically you pin the next visits of each vehicle and optimize all unpinned visits, including the new visit(s).
Alternatively, you can use **Recommended Fit** (assign each visit as it comes in very quickly without doing deep optimization, unlike real-time planning). Both are explained in the docs.